# Asynchronous cURL using POST

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I am making a **command line** application. I need to send out multiple POST requests via cURL simultaneously after I have performed log in procedures - meaning outgoing requests must send session id etc.

The chain of events is as follows:

1. I open cURL connection with curl_init
2. I log in to remote site sending POST request with curl_exec and get returned HTML code as response
3. I send multiple POST requests to same site simultaneously.

I was thinking of using something like that:

```
// Init connection

$ch = curl_init();

// Set curl options

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Perform login

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mysite/login.php");
$post = array('username' => 'username' , 'password' => 'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Send multiple requests after being logged on

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);

for($i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++){
    $post = array('myvar' => 'changing_value');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.myweb.ee/changing_url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as only the first request in loop seems to be sent.

Using `curl_multi_init` would probably one solution but I don't know if i can pass it the same cURL handle multiple times with changed options for each.

I don't need any response from server for those simultaneous requests but it would be awesome if it also can be done somehow.

It would be perfect if someone could push me in the right direction how to do it.

Comment: Judging from the code you've shown, that should actually work.

Comment: this would work, but the request would be done sequentially, by using curl_multi you can send all request at once, and then process all results when they're done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create a new curl handle for every request, and then register it with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php

here is some code i ripped out and adapted from my code base, have in mind that you should add error checking in there.

```
function CreateHandle($url , $data) {
    $curlHandle = curl_init($url);

    $defaultOptions = array (
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt' ,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt' ,

        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip" ,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true ,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true ,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
    );

    curl_setopt_array($curlHandle , $defaultOptions);

    return $curlHandle;
}

function MultiRequests($urls , $data) {
    $curlMultiHandle = curl_multi_init();

    $curlHandles = array();
    $responses = array();

    foreach($urls as $id => $url) {
        $curlHandles[$id] = CreateHandle($url , $data[$id]);
        curl_multi_add_handle($curlMultiHandle, $curlHandles[$id]);
    }

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($curlMultiHandle, $running);
    } while($running > 0);

    foreach($curlHandles as $id => $handle) {
        $responses[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($curlMultiHandle, $handle);
    }
    curl_multi_close($curlMultiHandle);

    return $responses;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I probably need to use - rebuild the system a bit and make all requests run on different curl objects.

Comment: How do I identify curl object, when I cant build a loop, which waits for all the queries to be executed and finished. I got this one loop, which does everything, looks which queries to push to the multi object, execute them and see if they are finished. If there's a way to attach ID to curl handle returned by curl_init.

Comment: you can use curl_multi_info_read to get a single handle from multi_handle, and just cast the handle to integer to use it as identifier, if you need i can try to look in my code base for example of that as well

Comment: Oh right, I have done it before but forgotten it already - no need for the code. Now tell me, does curl_multi_exec execute all previously added curl object or only one of them (first one added) - so I need to call it multiple times.

Comment: it processes all added handles, and then sets the $running to indicate if all handles are done or not, so you'll likely just need to run it once in a loop

Answer (score 2):

There's a faster, more efficient option ... that doesn't require that you use any curl at all ...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php
http://pthreads.org

See github for latest source, releases on pecl ....

I will say this, file_get_contents may seem appealing, but PHP was never designed to run threaded in this manner, it's socket layers and the like give no thought to consumption you might find that it's better to fopen and sleep inbetween little reads to conserve CPU usage ... however you do it it will be much better ... and how you do it depends on what kind of resources you want to dedicate the task ...

Comment: Nice solution! I wish there was some good example how to install the libraries on PHP running on windows as I found this project [link](http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32/).

Comment: There are dll's for download on github ... https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/downloads install like any other php extension ...