# Insert scraped variable into mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been looking to make a very simple database, which has 4 columns. First is a local int that auto incriments, 2nd is a single digit ID int, 3rd is another INT and fourth is the scraped variable (string). Problem I am having however is with the actual inserting of the 3 variables.

I have the `$charIDs` variable increase by 1 at the end of a for loop, which is used in the url I am scraping. the `$server` variable is just a static int, and the `$trimmedName` variable is the actual text I scrape from each web page and it works great.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/asddas/asda/search?=$charIDs");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tags = $xpath->query('//*[@id="div_contents"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd/span/text()');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    trim($name = $tag->nodeValue);
}
if ($name != null){

$trimmedName = trim($name);

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO players (serverID, charID, charName)
VALUES ('$server', '$charIDs', '$trimmedName')";

$conn->close();
$name = null;
$trimmedName = null;
}
$charIDs++;
}
```

I've checked variables, table names, etc and I am not sure why it isn't working. I am able to insert rows manually into the database.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? It would also be helpful to see the `players` table schema. paste the results of `desc players` into the question.

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();` should be moved outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things I have noticed about your script.

1) You are not executing the query, this is the big problem.
2) You should still be using parametrized queries.
3) Why bother recreating the mysqli and statement objects on each iteration.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO players (serverID, charID, charName) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

if (!$stmt) {
    die('could not create statement: ' . $conn->error);
}

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    // curl and XML stuff here
    $binded = $stmt->bind_param('iis', $server, $charIDs, $trimmedName);
    if ($binded) {
        echo ($stmt->execute() ? 'Inserted' : 'Did not insert');
    }
    $charIDs++;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Yes you are right I feel like a total idiot for not noticing. I copied all the database code over from a script I wrote about a month ago and was doing this all late night. I had the connection info outside of the for loop I think I failed when writing this. Thanks a lot for your help. 

This is going to be ran a few hundred thousand times. The re-written code you have do you think it will speed it up? Currently it is adding about 10 rows per second.

Comment: I would move the `curl_init` call out side the loop as well. But to run the loop a hundred thousand is going to take a while. Curl has an asynchronous mode but I have never used it. This page might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839793/asynchronous-curl-using-post

Comment: Okay I'll have a look. I'll move it to before the loop and see if that helps any.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly obvious, but I don't see anywhere where you execute the SQL statement. I can't comment on how safe this is as you don't provide what comprises the variables. Hopefully you're incorporating [best practices](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) for your data

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (serverID, charID, charName)
VALUES ('$server', '$charIDs', '$trimmedName')";
$conn->query($sql);
```